# smoothScrollTo - prompter effect

Tags: android, smooth-scrolling

I try to do like a prompter effect. smoothly move line by line but smoothScrollTo isnt't so smooth. What I'd like to do is the text appearing slowly in the scrollview. like a TV prompter.
any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by doing:

```
    private void displayWPM(){
// 
// 8 lines per minute to reach 50 wpm = 6 words per line
// correspondig to my scrollview width = 500dp
// and textview large font
//
        new CountDownTimer(300000, 195) {
        int i =0;
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                sv.smoothScrollTo(0,i*1);
                i++;
            }

            public void onFinish() {
 //               text.setText("Done");
            }

        }.start();

    }
```